# Attribute Error Python from a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an attribute error in python, but i have imported everything i need to. This is confusing because it seems logical that this would work there is nothing out or order, i don't think though i am saying that coming from a java background.

This is in a file called utils.py

```
import runMain


def isUser(credentialsInput):
    return credentialsInput in runMain.users


def isReserved(names):
    for strings in runMain.roomName:
        if names in strings:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def getIndex(e, check):
    return e.index(check)


def findInArray(e, searchName):
    runMain.i = 0
    while runMain.i < len(e):
        test = e[runMain.i]
        if searchName in test:
            break
    return runMain.i


def registerUser(creds):
    runMain.users.__add__(len(runMain.users), creds)


def runCredentialCheck():
    runMain.username = input("admin$ -u>>> ")
    runMain.password = input("admin$ -p>>> ")
    runMain.credentials = runMain.username + ":" + runMain.password
    return isUser(runMain.credentials)
```

I have another file called runMain where i have the following code:

```
import utils
import sys


TOTAL_ROOMS = 500
rooms = []
suite = []
reservations = []
reservationParts = []
roomNum = 0
suiteOut = ""
suiteF = ""
name = ""
userInput = ""
suiteT = " and is a suite"
utils.users.append("foo:hello")


userInput = input(">>> ")
while True:
        if userInput == "new -r":
                utils.username = input("admin$ -u>>> ")
                utils.password = input("admin$ -p>>> ")
                utils.credentials = utils.username + ":" + utils.password
                if utils.isUser(credentialsInput=utils.credentials):
                        userInput = input("rsr# -n ")
                        reservationParts = userInput.split()
                        roomNum = reservationParts[0]
                        name = reservationParts[1]
                        if name in rooms:
                                print(">>> Room is occupied")
                        elif name in utils.roomName:
                                print(">>> Room is occupied")
                        rooms.append(roomNum)
                        utils.roomName.append(name)
                        utils.loopCount = 0
                        if "--suite" in userInput:
                                suite.append(True)
                                suiteOut = suiteT
                        else:
                                suite.append(False)
                                suiteOut = suiteF
                        reservations.append("Room " + roomNum + " is filled by " +
                                            utils.roomName.__getitem__(utils.loopCount) + suiteOut)
                        for ints in rooms:
                                if suite.__getitem__(utils.loopCount):
                                        suiteOut = suiteT
                                else:
                                        suiteOut = suiteF
                                sys.stdout.write("Room " + ints + " is filled by " +
                                                 utils.roomName.__getitem__(utils.loopCount) + suiteOut)
                                print()
                                utils.loopCount += 1
                        userInput = input(">>> ")
                        if userInput == "quit()":
                                break
                else:
                        print("Invalid Credentials")
        elif userInput == "new -u":
                if utils.runCredentialCheck():
                    utils.username = input("new -u -u>>> ")
                    utils.password = input("new -u -p>>> ")
                    utils.registerUser(creds=(utils.username + ":" + utils.password))
                else:
                    print("Invalid Credentials")
                userInput = input(">>> ")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm getting the error:
AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'runCredentialCheck'.

Comment: where is `utils` being imported from?

Comment: utils is a file it is imported in the runMain file

Comment: Well your issue here isn't with the `runMain` import but with the `utils` import. Can you post the contents of `utils`?

Comment: utils content is posted in the question

Comment: Is there anything else in your `runMain` file?

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: And you have both of these files in the same directory?

Comment: yes i do, i promise hjhhhhhhhhhh (i have to do this to post my comment)

Comment: I think one of your main problems is you have a circular import. `runMain` is importing `utils` which is importing `runMain` which is importing `utils`, etc. Try separating these scripts out a bit more (handing relevant data to the functions in `utils` and returning everything that's necessary). This will certainly help.

Comment: I've posted an answer that explains this particular issue, but you're going to run into more immediately after fixing it and the large number of global variables, many of which don't appear to be initialized, will make it hard to debug. Furthermore, you shouldn't ever need to call `__dunder__` methods explicitly; they're mostly for overriding built-in functions and operators. Instead of doing `a.__getitem__(b)` just use `a[b]`, with square brackets

Comment: new to python coming from java and i use array lists far more often than actual arrays so i thoughts what you would do haha

Comment: Ah, I see. Java doesn't have operator overloading so `ArrayList` has to use `.get()`, but in Python lists, dictionaries, strings and other indexable sequences all use the square bracket syntax. You would override `__getitem__` in your own class if you wanted to support that syntax as well. [This page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) describes what all the special methods do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has

- a circular import loop (`runMain` imports `utils` which imports `runMain` which imports...)
- a module containing (non-definition) code that is run when the module is imported

Both of these are poor practices, partially because in combination they break. Circular module dependencies are usually not a problem, because Python only runs the code in each module once. However, there's one situation in which Python may run it twice: when the module is named on the command line.

```
# foo.py
import bar
print("in foo")
```

```
# bar.py
import foo
print("in bar")
```

```
$ python3 foo.py
in foo
in bar
in foo
```

To fix this, you should break the dependency: if you need `utils` to have access to items in `runMain`, either move them into `utils` or put them in a third module that is included by both `utils` and `runMain`; and guard the code inside `runMain.py` with an `if` statement that only runs when the file is being run directly from the command line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # code here will be executed only when the module is run directly
```

This is a common Python idiom.

Incidentally, I haven't tried to make sense of all your code, but some of the assignment statements in `utils` probably don't do what you want, because they affect the "inner" `runMain` module and not the "outer" layer (which runs as `__main__` instead of `runMain`). The best solution to this problem is not to have cyclic module dependencies, but if you do, you should never execute any of the modules in the cycle directly.